# How AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior's math works?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I would watch the math flow of the `offsetChildAsNeeded` method in AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior on running scrolling changes.

As it is private method and private is `mOffsetDelta`, how can programmatically monitor them?

(It is not clear how the method uses `offset` too.)

```
private void offsetChildAsNeeded(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    final CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior =
                ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior();
    if (behavior instanceof Behavior) {
        // Offset the child, pinning it to the bottom the header-dependency, maintaining
        // any vertical gap, and overlap
        final Behavior ablBehavior = (Behavior) behavior;
        final int offset = ablBehavior.getTopBottomOffsetForScrollingSibling();
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, (dependency.getBottom() - child.getTop())
                + ablBehavior.mOffsetDelta
                + getVerticalLayoutGap()
                - getOverlapPixelsForOffset(dependency));
        }
    }
```

***NOTE: are welcome and could be accepted replies also the ones that explain details on math's logic of `getTopBottomOffsetForScrollingSibling()`, of `(dependency.getBottom() - child.getTop())`,  and on the content of `mOffsetDelta`***

Comment: It would be better if you explain your final goal, rather than the way you are planning to achieve it.

Comment: the final goal is learning how the behavior works while scroll changes

Comment: Copy the `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` class to your project, make changes, point your `AppBarLayout`'s `app:layout_behavior` to it, profit.

Comment: I am trying so but there is not visibility out of the original package for the parent HeaderScrollingViewBehavior, and for mOffsetDelta in AppBarLayout.Behavior.

Comment: I would very much like to use to results of `offsetChildAsNeeded` in a subclass of `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. Any updates on this?

Comment: no news at now.

Comment: @ForrestBice A new good answer by kris larson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reverse-engineer this code, but in the end it's academic because us mere mortal (i.e. non-Google) programmers can't access the values and methods shown here.  I guess they figure that the less of their library we can actually *use*, the fewer bug reports we'll file.  Sigh.

But here's a brief explanation:

First of all that code line

```
    final int offset = ablBehavior.getTopBottomOffsetForScrollingSibling();
```

appears to be a vestigial remnant of an earlier revision, since `offset` is never actually used.  The newer expression must be a little more accurate in more cases.

`ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom()` is not a set (absolute) operation, but an additive (relative) operation.  So let's assume the normal logic and consider that this behavior essentially puts the scrolling view directly underneath the app bar layout.  Typically, then, the bottom of the app bar and the top of the scrolling view have the same value. Since the app bar layout (dependency) has changed and the scrolling view (child) hasn't (yet), then

```
    dependency.getBottom() - child.getTop()
```

is the relative amount that the child's vertical offset needs to be adjusted.

If my reading of the code is correct, that `mOffsetDelta` in the app bar layout's behavior is only non-zero in the case that the app bar layout has an offset interpolater.  Typically the app bar *itself* won't move in a parallax fashion, so `mOffsetDelta` is zero for practically all the cases we care about.  `getVerticalLayoutGap` and `getOverlapPixelsForOffset` deal with layout params like `overlapTop`.

But it turns out that you can do most of this without those edge cases in your own behavior subclass just by doing this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child,
                                          View dependency) {
        // get the bottom of the app bar layout
        int bottom = dependency.getBottom();

        // position the top of the scrolling view there
        return setTopAndBottomOffset(bottom);
    }
```

I find it's a little easier to work with absolute offsets rather than relative offsets.  So implementing a scrolling behavior is mostly a matter of determining where the dependent view is and where the scrolling view needs to be based on that.